# How to output text with all hyphens from what was written in textarea?

Tags: css, textarea

Django: I need to output the text that I wrote in the form in the textinput field with all hyphens and red lines to the template. But my text is solid.

At first, my text went beyond the blog, but I solved it using word-break in a css file, I tried to play with css, but nothing happened, the text still goes solid. I output the text written in the textarea field to the  tag.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us understand the problem more fully.